# Using Day View calendar

Tags: java, android

I started use the [Calendar Library Etar](https://github.com/Etar-Group/Etar-Calendar). It is great library. But I have a question.

I need to use just `Day View` mode.

How can I use/cut only that classes which relate to the `Day View` and delete expect those? Thanks advance